# How to add rounded corners to a UIView with gradient applied?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, cgrect

I've written custom subclass of UIView that draws a gradient inside of it:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class PlayerCellView: UIView {

var startColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.75, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)
var endColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.07, green:0.42, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    let locations : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as CFArray, locations: locations)
    context?.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: CGPoint.zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height), options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)
    }

}
```

How would I now apply rounded edges to this view?

Answer (score 2):

use this extension method:

```
extension UIView {
    func addGradientLayer(with colors: [CGColor], startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, locations: [NSNumber] = [0.0, 1.0], frame: CGRect = CGRect.zero) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors

        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint

        gradientLayer.locations = locations
        gradientLayer.frame = frame

        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a rounded corner UIView with gradient using the following method:

```
func makeCircularGradient(){
    let circularView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(circularView)
    circularView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    circularView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    circularView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    circularView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    circularView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = circularView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor,
                       UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    circularView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)


    let circularPath = CGMutablePath()
    circularPath.addArc(center: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width / 2, y: circularView.bounds.height / 2), radius: circularView.bounds.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true, transform: .identity)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = circularPath
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    circularView.layer.mask = maskLayer


}
```

- Make a UIView and set the constraints as you see fit
- Make a CAGradientLayer with colours of your choice
- Make a circular mask layer and apply to the UIView.

The result will be something like below:
[image]

Making a curved corner radius View with gradient is a little bit more difficult than the circular one. And can be done like :

```
func makeCurvedCornerGradient(){
    let circularView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(circularView)
    circularView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    circularView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    circularView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    circularView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    circularView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = circularView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor,
                       UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    circularView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)


    let circularPath = CGMutablePath()

    circularPath.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: 20, y: 0))
    circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width - 20, y: 0))
    circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width, y: 20), control: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width, y: 0))
    circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width, y: circularView.bounds.height - 20))
    circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width - 20, y: circularView.bounds.height), control: CGPoint.init(x: circularView.bounds.width, y: circularView.bounds.height))
    circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: 20, y: circularView.bounds.height))
    circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: circularView.bounds.height - 20), control: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: circularView.bounds.height))
    circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 20))
    circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: 20, y: 0), control: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0))


    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = circularPath
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    circularView.layer.mask = maskLayer


}
```

Change the values according to your need.
Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so far but I still have a question: My scenario is that I have multiple cells in a table and right now I only have a view similar to your output layered over every cell (changed some values like colour and such) but what I want is the gradient to be in the background. So how do I a) move the view into the background and b) make it snap to the frame set by its superview? I'm sorry to bother you but I'm fairly new to drawing with Swift so I can't seem to be able to figure it out myself.

Comment: Instead of the the circular View that I use in my code, add the maskLayer to your UITableViewCell. 
1) Add a circularView to your cell.
2) After setting the constraints of circularView with respect to your cell.layer and do cell.layoutIfNeeded()
3) Add the maskLayer to your cell.
4) Now you may make any other view on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

**You can possibly use the Following Code:**

```
func setGradientBorderWidthColor(view: UIView)
{
    let gradientColor = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientColor.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: view.frame.size)
    gradientColor.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

    let pathWithRadius = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:view.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .topLeft, .bottomLeft , .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 3
    shape.path = pathWithRadius.cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradientColor.mask = shape
    view.layer.mask = shape
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientColor)
}
```

**You can use this as:**

```
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
    setGradientBorderWidthColor(view: myView)
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

**Output is like this:**

[image]

Hope this Helps!